# Is there a way to verify that UI element is located in a certain part of the screen in Playwright?

Tags: typescript, user-interface, web, automated-tests, playwright

I am new to `Playwright` and just recently started trying to implement tests with it.
My question is, is there a way to test that some web element is in certain location on the web page? For example, if I have an .svg logo on my web page, would I be able to test that it appears on the top left part of the screen with playright? Would I be able to test that the a certain button is located at the right bottom of a certain web container?

I couldn't find any examples online with regards to those specifics. I am using **TypeScript** for my tests.

Comment: Yes, you can. Refer to this : https://playwright.dev/docs/other-locators#css-matching-elements-based-on-layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playwright has visual comparison testing which you might want to look into.  It checks how the page being tested looks compared to a golden file (the correct expected output).  It tests visual elements.  Here is the example from the Playwright docs:

```
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';

test('example test', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('https://playwright.dev');
  await expect(page).toHaveScreenshot();
});
```

You can see more about how this works in the [Playwright docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-snapshots) or on [this tutorial](https://www.lambdatest.com/learning-hub/playwright-visual-regression-testing) about visual regression testing which I found helpful.